# Access tables which are created in dbo in MSSQL server using jdbc connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have connect MSSQL server through java using following Code

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DATABASENAME=;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER", "DB_USER_NAME", "DB_PASSWORD");
```

After that I am able to connect database and execute sql script without giving any object name. for example

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
```

Now, I have some tables which are got created under `dbo` and I want to access them using same connect.
How Can I go with this?
I have try with

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TEST_TABLE1
```

but it says that this table is not there in database.

Comment: add your database name in connection string

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;

Comment: I had tried with that too. But the result is same.

Comment: Immediately after establishing your JDBC connection do `SELECT DB_NAME() AS currentdb` and verify that you are actually using the database you *think* you are using. If so, then log into SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with the same credentials you are using in your Java code and try to access the dbo. tables that way.

Comment: @Navnath Please provide more details of your problem so that we can help you in a more accurate way

Answer (score 0):

Make your DB user to the DB owner.