# Syntax error in prepared statement that runs in SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm getting a syntax error in my prepared statement even though my query runs in SQL Management Studio. I am using GlassFish 4.1.1. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried switching the syntax around a bit but I always get an error.

Here is my connection pool code:

```java
try {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/" + database);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my query code:

```java
ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool("BoxPointHAMBURGO");
Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    String query = "SELECT Tabla FROM BoxPointHAMBURGO.dbo.NombresTablas";

    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "." at line 1 column 39.
```

Comment: Why do you have two dots?

Comment: It's like puting .dbo.NombresTablas in this case, that one also gives me an error in my Java code but not in SQL Management Studio

Comment: What is `MAINDB` value? It that a non-empty constant? Can you please add the whole `query` variable value?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki yes, MAINDB is BoxPointHAMBURGO, I will edit my question

Comment: @KarolDowbecki yes

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786049/double-dot-table-qualifier/34786151) the double dot `..` operator results in default schema for the current database user being used for the query. However you shouldn't expect that SQL Management Studio query syntax will work when using JDBC. These are two completely different driver interfaces with different limitations, JDBC most likely being more restrictive.

You probably should select the `BoxPointHAMBURGO` database when you establish the JDBC connection. You would have to modify the JDBC URL as per [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017) the syntax is:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=BoxPointHAMBURGO
```

and then remove the database name from the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT Tabla FROM dbo.NombresTablas
```

Do note that tables under `dbo` schema [can only be accessed by the user that is the database owner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28669205/1602555).

Comment: I have that URL in my context.xml. I removed the database from the query but that just gave me a new error that says ```Schema 'DBO' does not exist``` even though I'm sure it does exist.

Comment: As per linked answer the user used to open database connection is not the database owner so it can't see `dbo.` objects.

Comment: re: "the double dot `..` operator results in default `dbo `schema being used for your query" - No, it results in the effective schema being the one that is specified as the default schema for the current database user. Very often that is `dbo`, but not always.